# Algorithm for combining two trees

Tags: algorithm, tree, language-agnostic

I'm looking for an algorithm to merge or combine two trees (if possible). While I've tried to search the web in general, as well as Stack Overflow in particular, I haven't been able to find anything that resembles what I'm after.

Since the problem seems of a general nature, I find it unlikely that it's not already a solved problem. Thus, I'm inclined to think that my failure to find anything stems from my use of incorrect or imprecise search terms.

*I'm not asking anyone to write code for me. The question is whether there's a known algorithm for the following kind of problem.*

Given two trees, I'd like to merge them if they have common nodes.

For example,

```
1         1         1
|         |         |
+-2   +   +-4   =   +-2
|                   |
+-3                 +-3
                    |
                    +-4
```

because the two trees to the left of the equals sign have a node in common (`1`).

It might also be the case that the two trees have more than a single node in common:

```
1           1           1
|           |           |
+-2         +-2         +-2
| |         | |         | |
| +-3   +   | +-6   =   | +-3
| |         | |         | |
| +-4       | +-7       | +-4
|           |           | |
+-5         +-8         | +-6
                        | |
                        | +-7
                        |
                        +-5
                        |
                        +-8
```

because the sub-trees share a common path from the root.

---

*Edit 2023-07-08 18:18Z*
We can assume that all node labels are unique. In the examples, I've used integers for readability reasons, but in reality, the nodes are going to be identified by GUIDs.

Commenters have requested more examples, so I'll try to add one more. Essentially, I need to 'splice' one tree into the place another tree if they share a sub-path. Again, keep in mind that node IDs can be assumed unique.

```
1             2           1
|             |           |
+-2           +-4         +-2
| |             |         | |
| +-3     +     +-8   =   | +-3
| |             |         | |
| +-4           +-9       | +-4
|   |                     |   |
|   +-5                   |   +-5
|   |                     |   |
|   +-6                   |   +-6
|                         |   |
+-7                       |   +-8
                          |   |
                          |   +-9
                          |
                          +-7
```

Here, the `2, 4` path exists in both trees, so the result combines the subtree of the `2, 4` path of the first tree with the subtree of the `2-4` path of the second tree. (These ASCII trees aren't that easy to do by hand, so I hope I've rendered them correctly...)

In general, we can assume that subtrees (once detected) kan be added together with some semigroup operation. In the above example, I've used list concatenation, but in my real use case, I'm going to use set unions.

*End edit*

---

It's entirely conceivable that two trees have nothing in common, so that it's impossible to combine them. In that case, the function should return the two trees without merging them.

Thus, I'm looking for an algorithm with a type/signature like this:

```hs
Tree a -> Tree a -> [Tree a],
```

using Haskell syntax, or

```cs
IEnumerable<Tree<T>> Combine<T>(Tree<T> x, Tree<T> y)
```

using C# syntax.

Does a relevant algorithm exist, and if so, what is it's name and where can I read more about it?

It's not that I can't kludge something together, but if a known solution or algorithm exists, I'd like to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What if both trees have the same label for a node, but the path to that node is different? For instance, they both have a node `a`, but the first tree has path `root-x-a` to it, while the second has `root-a` or `root-y-a`?

Comment: I've tried to edit the question to supply more information, so perhaps the person voting to close would be so kind as to either retract that vote or tell me what more information is required. Please allow for time zones when considering response times - it may be day where you are, but night at my place, so if sufficiently unlucky, it could take me 8-10 hours to answer...

Comment: I can't draw these pretty ASCII diagrams in a comment, so I'll have to describe trees using unordered sets of parent->child relations i.e. edges. Your first example `Merge({1->2, 1->3}, {1->4}) = {1->2, 1->3, 1->4}`, second `Merge({1->2, 2->3, 2->4, 1->5}, {1->2, 2->6, 2->7, 1->8}) = {1->2, 1->5, 1->8, 2->3, 2->4, 2->6, 2->7}`. Is this alternative representation correct? Is `Merge({1->2, 2->3}, {1->3, 3->4}) = {1->2, 2->3, 3->4}` something that needs to be supported, or is this an invalid merge operation that should be failed gracefully, or is it guaranteed to never be requested?

Comment: @maxplus Thank you for elaborating. I hadn't thought of that last example of yours, because in my scenario, that's guaranteed to never be requested.

Comment: Then, if the two trees share the same root, it is the same algorithm as used e.g. for json or trie merging. If they don't, root of one of the trees needs to be found in another and json-like merge should be performed at that point. I don't know if the latter case is something widely used. If this is indeed what you need, I can describe it in more detail in an answer, with or without Python/C++ implementation.

Comment: @maxplus In my particular case, the root is going to be the same. Perhaps I've been trying to overgeneralise the problem...

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer to my comment, but don't see it yet. Or maybe the reply to maxplus is my answer. Can we be sure that if two trees have nodes with the same label, they have the same root-to-node path?

Comment: Are there any restrictions imposed on the representation of a tree, by pre-existing code base or language? The most straightforward would be to store tree as a root object and a map from child GUID to subtree, updating these maps by adding keys and modifying values while merging. But I imagine this might be a problem in Haskell, asking for a somewhat different purely functional algorithm using particular language instruments.

Comment: @maxplus The particular code base in question is F#, but I'm able to read code examples in other languages, too. I prefer Haskell, F#, or C#, but I think I'm able decipher most mainstream languages...

Comment: @trincot I'm sorry, I may have misunderstood the original question, but yes: If two trees have the same node, the node will also have the same parent in both trees.

Comment: @MarkSeemann In the third example roots are different (although it can be said that these two trees belong to the same super-tree which has root `1`, maybe that's what you meant). Is that example still relevant for you?

Answer (score 1):

If the two trees to be merged have equal root GUIDs, the algorithm is the following: a recursive merging function accepts two trees with equal roots, returns a merged tree with that root. Returned tree root has children that are root's children in exactly one of the input trees, and those children that are root's children in both input trees merged recursively.

If the two trees to be merged have different root GUIDs, first one of the roots has to be located in the other tree, then same-GUID merge performed at that point. If GUIDs are comparable and increase root-to-leaf, as is the case in all three examples, it is sufficient to search the greater root GUID in the other tree, otherwise both roots need to be searched. The algorithm to find a GUID in a tree is also a recursive function resembling DFS. If none of the two roots is present in the other tree, then the trees are disjoint and are not merged.

Example implementation in F# demonstrating 4 valid merge requests and 3 invalid, [run on sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=):

```fs
type Tree<'a> =
  struct
    val rootObject : 'a
    val children : Map<int, Tree<'a>>
    new(r, c) = { rootObject = r; children = c }
  end

type Obj =
  struct
    val guid : int
    new(g) = { guid = g }
  end

let rec mergeSameRoot (tree1 : Tree<Obj>) (tree2 : Tree<Obj>) : Tree<Obj> =
  let children : Map<int, Tree<Obj>> =
    Map.fold (fun (acc : Map<int, Tree<Obj>>) (guid : int) (subtree2 : Tree<Obj>) ->
      match Map.tryFind guid acc with
      | Some (subtree1 : Tree<Obj>) ->
          Map.add guid (mergeSameRoot subtree1 subtree2) acc
      | None -> Map.add guid subtree2 acc
    ) tree1.children tree2.children
  Tree (tree1.rootObject, children)

let rec tryMergeIntoFirst (tree1 : Tree<Obj>) (tree2 : Tree<Obj>) : Tree<Obj> option =
  if tree1.rootObject.guid = tree2.rootObject.guid then
    Some <| mergeSameRoot tree1 tree2
  elif Map.isEmpty tree1.children then
    None
  else
    let update : Option<int * Tree<Obj>> =
      Map.fold (fun (acc : Option<int * Tree<Obj>>) (guid : int) (subtree : Tree<Obj>) ->
        match tryMergeIntoFirst subtree tree2 with
        | Some (result : Tree<Obj>) -> Some (guid, result)
        | None -> acc
      ) None tree1.children
    match update with
      | Some (guid : int, subtree: Tree<Obj>) ->
          Some <| Tree (tree1.rootObject, Map.add guid subtree tree1.children)
      | None -> None

let tryMergeEither (tree1 : Tree<Obj>) (tree2 : Tree<Obj>) : Tree<Obj> option =
  match tryMergeIntoFirst tree1 tree2 with
  | Some (result : Tree<Obj>) -> Some result
  | None -> tryMergeIntoFirst tree2 tree1

let tryMergeReturnList (tree1 : Tree<Obj>) (tree2 : Tree<Obj>) : Tree<Obj> list =
  match tryMergeEither tree1 tree2 with
  | Some (result : Tree<Obj>) -> [result]
  | None -> [tree1; tree2]

let examplesDemo () =
  let rec printTree (tree1 : Tree<Obj>) =
    printf "%d: {" tree1.rootObject.guid
    Map.iter (fun k v -> printTree v) tree1.children
    printf "}, "

  let printMerge tree1 tree2 =
    printTree tree1
    printf "\n+\n"
    printTree tree2
    printf "\n=\n"
    match tryMergeReturnList tree1 tree2 with
    | [a] -> printTree a
    | [a; b] -> printf "Disjoint"
    | _ -> failwith "Unreachable code"
    printf "\n\n"

  let keyValue obj value = (obj, Tree (Obj obj, value))
  let leaf obj = keyValue obj Map.empty

  let example1Tree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 2; leaf 3])
  let example1Tree2 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 4])

  let example2Tree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 5;
    keyValue 2 <| Map.ofList [leaf 3; leaf 4]
  ])
  let example2Tree2 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 8;
    keyValue 2 <| Map.ofList [leaf 6; leaf 7]
  ])

  let example3Tree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 7;
    keyValue 2 <| Map.ofList [leaf 3;
      keyValue 4 <| Map.ofList [leaf 5; leaf 6]
    ]
  ])
  let example3Tree2 = Tree (Obj 2, Map.ofList [
    keyValue 4 <| Map.ofList [leaf 8; leaf 9]
  ])

  let disjointTree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 2])
  let disjointTree2 = Tree (Obj 3, Map.ofList [leaf 4])

  printMerge example1Tree1 example1Tree2
  printMerge example2Tree1 example2Tree2
  printMerge example3Tree1 example3Tree2
  printMerge disjointTree1 disjointTree2

  printfn "\nInvalid requests:"

  let silentError1Tree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 2])
  let silentError1Tree2 = Tree (Obj 2, Map.ofList [leaf 1])

  let silentError2Tree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [
    keyValue 2 <| Map.ofList [leaf 3]
  ])
  let silentError2Tree2 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 3])

  let silentError3Tree1 = Tree (Obj 1, Map.ofList [leaf 2; leaf 3])
  let silentError3Tree2 = Tree (Obj 2, Map.ofList [leaf 3])

  printMerge silentError1Tree1 silentError1Tree2
  printMerge silentError2Tree1 silentError2Tree2
  printMerge silentError3Tree1 silentError3Tree2

examplesDemo ()
```

Comment: What about the third example?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit, "In my particular case, the root is going to be the same". My understanding is that the third example isn't needed. If it turns out that it is, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

One benefit of being encouraged to explain and detail a problem is that it helps you understand the problem better. Thanks to all the questions, I think that I now have an algorithm. At least, I have a proof of concept that seems to work.

In short, the algorithm is this: *Find a spanning forest of the union of the edges of the two trees.*

To elaborate: Convert each tree to a set of edges, take the union of those two sets, and find a spanning forest of the union. If the two trees have just one node in common, that spanning forest will be a single spanning tree (I think).

---

To illustrate, I created a Haskell proof of concept. The function in itself is almost trivial, while I had to write some fairly convoluted code to accommodate the awkward API of [Data.Graph](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Graph.html).

First, required imports:

```hs
import Data.Set (Set, (\\))
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Map.Strict (Map)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import Data.Graph
import Data.Tree
```

I'll show some code and how to interact with it in GHCi, so first, here are the trees in the OP:

```hs
t1 = Node 1 [Node 2 [], Node 3 []]
t2 = Node 1 [Node 4 []]
t3 = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 [], Node 4 []], Node 5 []]
t4 = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 6 [], Node 7 []], Node 8 []]
t5 = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 [], Node 4 [Node 5 [], Node 6 []]], Node 7 []]
t6 = Node 2 [Node 4 [Node 8 [], Node 9 []]]
```

Converting a tree to a list of edges is a one-liner (if you ignore the type declaration, which is optional, but idiomatic):

```hs
edgesOfTree :: Tree a -> [(a, a)]
edgesOfTree (Node x xs) = xs >>= \t -> (x, rootLabel t) : edgesOfTree t
```

Using it gives you results like these:

```
ghci> edgesOfTree t1
[(1,2),(1,3)]
ghci> edgesOfTree t6
[(2,4),(4,8),(4,9)]
```

Another way to represent the same data is with an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). While I suppose I could have written a function to convert directly from `Tree a` to this format, apparently I found it easier (or rather: less difficult - who am I kidding?) to do it in two steps:

```hs
edgesToAdjacencyList :: (Foldable t, Ord k, Ord a) => t (k, a) -> Map k (Set a)
edgesToAdjacencyList =
  foldr (\(p, c) -> Map.insertWith Set.union p (Set.singleton c)) Map.empty
```

Here's how use of those two functions may look:

```
ghci> edgesToAdjacencyList $ edgesOfTree t1
fromList [(1,fromList [2,3])]
ghci> edgesToAdjacencyList $ edgesOfTree t6
fromList [(2,fromList [4]),(4,fromList [8,9])]
```

The next step is a direct result of my decision to use *Data.Graph* to turn this kind of representation back to one or more trees. The [graphFromEdges](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Graph.html#v:graphFromEdges) function has a very particular API, so I needed a function to convert to its required input format.

This is easily the most convoluted code in the proof of concept, but I consider it an artefact of *Data.Graph* rather than essential complexity of the algorithm itself. In other words, an implementation detail:

```hs
toGraphEdges :: Ord a => Map a (Set a) -> [(a, a, [a])]
toGraphEdges m =
  let edges = (\(k, s) -> (k, k, toList s)) <$> Map.toList m
      leaves =
        fmap (\x -> (x, x, []))
        $ toList
        $ Set.unions (Map.elems m) \\ Set.fromList (Map.keys m)
  in edges ++ leaves
```

What complicates this function is that the `graphFromEdges` function doesn't infer the leaves from the adjacency list, so one has to explicitly list them.

Here's how that looks in GHCi:

```
ghci> toGraphEdges $ edgesToAdjacencyList $ edgesOfTree t1
[(1,1,[2,3]),(2,2,[]),(3,3,[])]
ghci> toGraphEdges $ edgesToAdjacencyList $ edgesOfTree t6
[(2,2,[4]),(4,4,[8,9]),(8,8,[]),(9,9,[])]
```

Since the `graphFromEdges` function takes a list of triples, a little utility function also turns out to be helpful:

```hs
fstOf3 :: (a, b, c) -> a
fstOf3 (x, _, _) = x
```

All required building blocks are now in place to implement the desired functionality:

```hs
unite :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a -> [Tree a]
unite x y =
  let edges = edgesOfTree x ++ edgesOfTree y
      (graph, nodeFromVertex, _) =
        graphFromEdges $ toGraphEdges $ edgesToAdjacencyList edges
  in fmap (fstOf3 . nodeFromVertex) <$> dff graph
```

The first expression converts the two trees to lists of edges and concatenates them. At this point, the list may contain duplicates, but since `toGraphEdges` converts lists to sets, it effectively deals with that issue.

Here are the examples from the OP:

```
ghci> putStrLn $ drawForest $ fmap show <$> unite t1 t2
1
|
+- 2
|
+- 3
|
`- 4
```

If you don't know Haskell, this may look obscure, but the function call is just  `unite t1 t2` - the rest of the expression (to the left of `unite t1 t2`) is only to print the result as a nice tree.

```
ghci> putStrLn $ drawForest $ fmap show <$> unite t3 t4
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 3
|  |
|  +- 4
|  |
|  +- 6
|  |
|  `- 7
|
+- 5
|
`- 8
```

The third example is supported, too:

```
ghci> putStrLn $ drawForest $ fmap show <$> unite t5 t6
1
|
+- 2
|  |
|  +- 3
|  |
|  `- 4
|     |
|     +- 5
|     |
|     +- 6
|     |
|     +- 8
|     |
|     `- 9
|
`- 7
```

So far, this is only a proof of concept. I haven't yet translated it to F# and used it for my actual purpose, so it's possible that I may have to adjust some details, but I think that this looks promising.